# Regex with one or more letters followed with optional digits with total length minimum 8?

Tags: regex, html

I am using pattern in HTML5 validation.
I want a regex to check for such username format:

```
<letters+><digits*> : total length minimum 8
-> starting with letters then optional digits.
```

examples: w1234567, qweqr123, jsgwiuegn1274124, qwerasdf, awdjwuadhuf, etc.

wrong examples: 12345678, qwe12qwe, 12qweqwe, qweq12, etc.

I tried `([A-z]+[0-9]*){8,}`, It's not working as expected.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your regex  - `([A-z]+[0-9]*){8,}` - matches 8 or more sequences of 1 or chars inside `[A-z]` range (that matches more than just letters, see [Why is this regex allowing a caret?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29771926/3832970)) and 0+ digits. Thus, it does not really set the length restriction.

You may use a lookahead based regex:

```
pattern="(?=[a-zA-Z\d]{8})[A-Za-z]+\d*"
```

Note that the `pattern` is anchored by default and will be passed to the regex engine as `^(?:(?=[a-zA-Z\d]{8})[A-Za-z]+\d*)$`. To play it safe, you may add them explicitly: `pattern="^(?=[a-zA-Z\d]{8})[A-Za-z]+\d*$"`

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/pYfFVn/1)

*Details*:

- `^` - matches the start of string (implicit)
- `(?=[a-zA-Z\d]{8})` - a positive lookahead that requires 8 alphanumeric chars from the start of the string
- `[A-Za-z]+` - 1 or more (`+`) ASCII letters
- `\d*`  - zero or more (`*`) digits
- `$` - end of string (implicit)

```css
input:valid {
  color: navy;
}
input:invalid {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<form name="form1"> 
 <input pattern="(?=[a-zA-Z\d]{8})[A-Za-z]+\d*" title=""/>
 <input type="Submit"/> 
</form>
```

Comment: Thanks!
**improvement:** I want minimum 8, so {8,} would work - I guess.
**doubt:** I thought [A-z] , [a-Z] are equivalent to [a-zA-Z]. can you explain it more?

Comment: Yes, for a minimum of 8, use `{8,}` limiting quantifier without the max argument, but actually, `{8}` will work the same way here since `$` is not used right after `{8}`. To restrict to just 8 chars, use `pattern="(?=[a-zA-Z\d]{8}$)[A-Za-z]+\d*"`. As for `[A-z]`, see [*Why is this regex allowing a caret?*](http://stackoverflow.com/a/29771926/3832970) Only use `[a-zA-Z]` to only match ASCII letters.